# open a dropdown menu by clicking a button

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 cdn and i want to open the dropdown without clicking the dropdown.

I use the navbar and want to show the "Dropdown Link":

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
      aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
            href="#"
            id="test"
            role="button"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="open()">Abrir</button>
```

In the component I tried to do the following but it doesn't work:

```
export class AppComponent {
  open() {
    const dropdown = document.getElementById('test');
    dropdown.click();
  }
}
```

I did it in stackblitz: [test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-5-dynamic-navbar-d8omww?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add bootstrap attributes to your button:

```
<button
    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
    type="button"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
    aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
 >
     Abrir
</button>
```

Link with code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-5-dynamic-navbar-77sj13?file=app/app.component.html

And it will work, BUT. Remember that your angular application should controls that elements, so mix external libraries with frameworks libraries (Angular, Vue, React) will allways couse trouble

For that uses there are special implementations, for example like this: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home
Angular bootstrap

Another option is to show the navbar with a ngIf (does not have animation by default)

Another link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-5-dynamic-navbar-hygpzq?file=app/app.component.html